# How to make Discord bot that check the left voice channel and erases the message from that channel

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I want to create a discord bot that erases the message from the channel People left

I tried this:

````
        if before.channel:
            for role in serverroles:
                rooles.append(get(self.guild.roles, name=role))
            await self.remove_roles(*rooles)
            if before.channel.members == []:
                chn = before.channel.id
                if chn == 743323003932115076:
                    channels = client.get_channel(ch1)
                    await channels.purge(limit=999)
                if chn == 743323035200913509:
                    channels = client.get_channel(ch2)
                    await channels.purge(limit=999)
                if chn == 743323078725075064:
                    channels = client.get_channel(ch3)
                    await channels.purge(limit=999)
                if chn == 743323177500803094:
                    channels = client.get_channel(ch4)
                    await channels.purge(limit=999)```

and I got AttributeError: 'VoiceChannel' object has no attribute 'purge'
````

Comment: There is no message in a voice channel, is there?

Comment: @Pac0 I agree. It seems like its purging on any channel and it should check to make sure it's in a TextChannel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is called **`on_voice_state_update`**, as the name says, it is for Voice channels and VoiceChannel can not be purged as there are no messages in it.